# Trouble linking SWC file

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, swc

I am trying to link the as3corelib library to use their JSON functionality following [this tutorial](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2006/03/28/tutorial-using-json-with-flex-2-and-actionscript-3/). But am having trouble compiling it. My command looks like:

```
mxmlc --strict=true -library-path+=as3corelib.swc --file-specs  myapp.mxml
```

But I am getting this error:

```
_divided_mx_managers_SystemManager.as(13): col: 14 Error: Interface method getVisibleApplicationRect in namespace mx.managers:ISystemManager not implemented by
class _divided_mx_managers_SystemManager.

public class _divided_mx_managers_SystemManager
```

What is the problem?

*Update: Is this because I am using Flex 3? The tutorial seems to be for Flex 2. If so, what do I need to do for Flex 3?*

Answer (score 1):

I found an older version of the library bundled with some tutorial which worked. Submitted a bug report to as3corelib, of course I am not entirely sure how valid the bug is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flex Builder 3 you can actually just take the swc file and put it in the libs directory.  This will automatically add it to your classpath and you should be able to use it from then on.  You may need to subsequently do a clean on the project to make sure it takes it in though.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue in Flex builder 4. I had to put the as3corelib sources into my source code for it to work alright.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the flex Gubmo sdk?
Looks like the method it's complaining about is in an interface that's part of Gumbo.
If so, then as3corelib probably won't work with it.

Comment: No, I am not. I haven't heard of Gumbo.